# Order of a principal term

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In [Yurii Nesterov's Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization](https://www.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-8853-9), there is a bound for the total number of iterations for some process. See page 109:

$$\left[\frac{1}{\ln(2(1-\kappa))} \ln\frac{t_0-t^*}{(1-\kappa) \epsilon}+2\right]\cdot \left[1+\sqrt\frac{L}{\mu}\ln\frac{2(L-\mu)}{\kappa \mu}\right]\\+\sqrt\frac{L}{\mu}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\max_{1\leq i \leq m}\{f_0(x_0)-t_0; f_i(x_0)\}\right)\label{eq1}\tag{1}$$

Then, the principal term in the above estimate is of the order
$$\ln\frac{t_0-t^*}{\epsilon} \sqrt\frac{L}{\mu} \ln\frac{L}{\mu} \label{eq2}\tag{2}$$

How did we arrive at statement $\eqref{eq2}$? Is that true the second term $\sqrt\frac{L}{\mu}\cdot\ln\big(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\max_{1\leq i \leq m}\{f_0(x_0)-t_0; f_i(x_0)\}\big)$ in $\eqref{eq1}$ is eliminated? I would appreciate any advice here.

Comment: Can you say what variable goes to infinity in this asymptotic analysis? If it's $L/\mu$, then he's right to drop the last term because $\log(L/\mu)$ increase while $\log(\epsilon^{-1}\max\cdots)$ is independent of $L/\mu$ and therefore treated as a constant. The coefficient of $\sqrt{L/\mu}\log(L/\mu)$ doesn't look right to me, it should be the large expression $2+\cdots$ in the first pair of brackets, unless something else goes to infinity also. It would really help to have the full original expression with context.

Comment: [It looks like only $\epsilon$ is changing. This is page 109][1]https://books.google.com/books?id=2-ElBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=page+109+nesterov+introductory+lectures+optimization&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx5f_xoIHeAhUFSN8KHaFsDUoQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=principal%20term%20in%20&f=false]

Comment: If only $\epsilon$ is changing, then it would be $\log\frac{t_0-t^*}{\epsilon} \sim -\log\epsilon$, so I'm not sure that's it.